# How do I add within the li markup?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm searching how to add a block inside a li markup.

What I have :

```
<ul>
   <li>
   <button onclick="expand()">+</button>
   Parent 1
   </li>
</ul>
```

What I want after clicking on the button.

```
<ul>
   <li>
   <button onclick="expand()">+</button>
   Parent 1
   <ul>
      <li> Child 1</li>
      <li> Child 2</li>
   </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My expand() function create the children ul with `document.createElement()` but I don't know how to insert it in the Parent 1 li.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Where does the data come from. Perhaps you should have the HTML at load time but hide it using display:none

Comment: Pass the reference to the button element, `onclick="expand(this)"` - then you can go upwards from there to the parent element. Or, if you are actually using jQuery already, stop doing “old-school” event handling via inline attributes, and use jQuery’s `.on()`, then you will have access to the element the event occurred upon via `$(this)`, and can navigate up from there using one of the methods jQuery provides for that.

Comment: And here's a live example demonstrating this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3jvs65tk/

Answer (score 0):

Either insert or toggle or both

```js
$(function() {
  $(".expand1").on("click",function(e) {
    if ($(this).siblings("ul").length === 0) { // only need to create once
      $(this).parent().append(`<ul class="extra">
        <li> Child 1</li>
        <li> Child 2</li>
     </ul>`)
   }
   $(this).siblings("ul").toggle(); // show or hide
   $(this).text($(this).siblings("ul").is(":visible") ? "-":"+"); // change + / -
  })
  
  $(".expand2").on("click",function(e) {
   $(this).siblings("ul").toggle()
   $(this).text($(this).siblings("ul").is(":visible") ? "-":"+")   
  })
})
```

```css
.extra { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>
   <button type="button" class="expand1">+</button>
   Parent 1
   </li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>
   <button type="button" class="expand2">+</button>
   Parent 1
   <ul class="extra">
      <li> Child 1</li>
      <li> Child 2</li>
   </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

```
<ul>
   <li>
   <button onclick="expand(event)">+</button>
   Parent 1
   </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript Code

```
function expand(event) {
var el = event.target.parentElement;

let lastChild = event.target.parentElement.lastChild;
let BeenHere = lastChild.tagName == "UL";

let childLI = document.createElement("li");
let childText = document.createTextNode(`Child ${BeenHere ? lastChild.childElementCount + 1 : 1} `);
childLI.appendChild(childText);

if(BeenHere){ 
    lastChild.appendChild(childLI); 
} 
else{ 
    let childUL = document.createElement("ul");
    el.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', childUL);
    childUL.appendChild(childLI);
}

}
```